# Using a while loop to iterate over array until it becomes empty in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops, while-loop

So I can't figure this out.

I'm looping over this array and deleting row after row and I can't find the right exit condition for the 'while' loop. What I have is the following:

```
array1 <- array(0,dim = c(5,2))
while(nrow(array1) > 0) {
    #do something
    array1 = array1[-1,]
 }
```

this gives me the error

```
Error in while (nrow(array1) > 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

whereas if I test it manually:

```
array1 = array1[-(1:5),]
nrow(array1) > 0
# [1] FALSE
```

thus (theoretically) breaking the condition in the 'while' loop. What is happening in the 'while' loop that leads to the error.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Yet another instance of `drop = FALSE` biting you when indexing in `array1[-1,]`. You want `array[-1,,drop = FALSE]`. ;)

Comment: And to add `nrow(vector)` returns `NULL`, `NULL > 0 ` returns `logical(0)`. `while(logical(0)){1}` returns your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `drop=FALSE` to avoid the array being turned into a vector in the last step and thus messing up the dimension indexing.

```
array1 <- array(0,dim = c(5,2))
while(nrow(array1) > 0) {
   #do something
   array1 = array1[-1,, drop=FALSE]
}
```